# Question marked as duplicate - original questions answer incomplete

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, duplicate-questions

I recently found an odd behavior in the ASP.NET MVC 5 framework and posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451373/radiobuttonfor-in-editortemplate-does-not-select-the-radiobutton) about it.

It was marked as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357468/radiobuttonfor-not-selecting-value-in-editor-templates), which is true, my mistake.

The reason I didn't realize it, was that the accepted answer in the other question does not answer the question I was trying to ask; it just provides a workaround. The question I was trying to ask is: **Why** does ASP.NET MVC 5 framework not mark the radio button checked even if it should?

A little later a helpful user found out that this is a bug in ASP.NET MVC 5 and posted it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/108).

Should I delete my question? Should I add my own answer in the original question which explains also **why** this is happening, not just a workaround? Or should the accepted answer be edited with more information?

What is the right course of action?

Comment: When the bug can't be fixed because the fix breaks existing code then the workaround is the correct solution.  You can annotate the answer with a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've found additional information that you think would be a useful addition to the canonical question, yes, you can post your own answer with that information.  As it's from an external source, be sure to both include enough information in the actual answer to answer the question, so that linking to the external source is not *necessary*, and also be sure to properly cite the source you are using.